# How to Read response data in for a particular time and check the data?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, receiver

I'm designing a software using `Visual Basic` to configure my device parameters. I'm writing the code  for windows forms app in `.vb`  In this I've to send a data to device and get response from device. If I didn't get the required response from device for a particular time I should output a message.

I've worked on serial writing, and made a simple software just to write some data. I've made a console to read the response from the device. I haven't got the slightest idea of checking the response and timeout in software.

I'll put a sample of code I've written.

```
  Private Sub BtnPub_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPub.Click
        Dim Data As String
        Timer1.Start()
        SerialPort1.Write("$PUB " & TbPub.Text & Environment.NewLine)
        SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 2000
        Timer1.Start()
        Try
            Data = SerialPort1.ReadLine()

        Catch ex As TimeoutException
            MessageBox.Show("No reponse", "BYE")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

The above code is a blunder, but this is my attempt. And i'm a virgin in VB.

***EDIT***

```
   Private Sub BtnPub_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPub.Click
        Dim Data As String
        SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 2000
        SerialPort1.Write("$PUB " & TbPub.Text & Environment.NewLine)
        Try
            Data = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
            If Data.Contains("OK") Then
                MessageBox.Show("SUCCESS", "Success")
            End If

        Catch ex As TimeoutException
            MessageBox.Show("No reponse" & Environment.NewLine & ex.ToString(), "BYE")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "BYE")

        End Try



    End Sub
```

This is aslo not working, am not getting anything to my software

Comment: I'm not really sure what the issue is. If the read operation times out then a `TimeoutException` is thrown and you're catching that, otherwise the `ReadLine` method returns and `Data` is set. If you don't want to continue if that exception is thrown then don't. What you actually do is up to you.

Comment: For the record, that `Timer` appears to be completely pointless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how to set the time for timeout exception?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I created another timer, cause i was confused on how the timerexception works. Can you help me on how to use timerexeption while reading a serial data

Comment: You're already using it. You really need to spend some time reading the documentation for the `SerialPort` class and its members. You are already setting the `ReadTimeout` to 2000, so you're already saying that a `TimeoutExecption` should be thrown if data is not read within 2 seconds. When you call `ReadLine`, either it returns the data read within two seconds or the exception that you're already catching is thrown. Your code already does what you want to do without any need for a `Timer`.

Comment: Oh, i tried running, and didnt get the required output, i'll check deeper, thanks for the help!

Comment: I have added edit to the post, I dont understand why am not getting response

Comment: Could it be that `Data` doesn't contain `"OK"`? That's the only possible outcome that won't display a message so did it occur to you to put a breakpoint on the `If` statement and see what the value of `Data` is?

Comment: Yes I did, i put breakpoints at if as well as exception, Data is showing 'Nothing'

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for bothering everyone! It was a hardware issue